# How did Captain Phasma regroup with the First Order so quickly after Starkiller Base?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, first-order

*The Force Awakens* ends with the

> destruction of Starkiller Base

this should have killed Captain Phasma, so we can only assume that she escaped. However, *The Last Jedi* takes place **minutes** after the end of *The Force Awakens* but features Captain Phasma with the First Order's forces. How did Captain Phasma regroup with the First Order so quickly?

Comment: *"The Last Jedi takes place minutes after the end of The Force Awakens"* - It actually takes place a few days later.

Comment: @Valorum So Rey and Luke were standing there for days on end? No wonder he had to go in and change clothes.

Comment: @MiloP - It also explains his poor attitude and need for milk

Comment: Nice dissolve...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story of her escape is covered in the four-part [*Captain Phasma*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Captain_Phasma) comics.

She escaped the compactor and made off in a TIE-Fighter in [*Captain Phasma #1*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Phasma_1) and we see (in [*Captain Phasma #4*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Phasma_4)) that her return to the fleet was not immediate. She actually took four days out to have a little side adventure, tracking down the person she framed as responsible for lowering the shields and making sure they couldn't tell anyone the contrary.

[image]

She returns to fleet just in time for them to attack the Rebel base on D'Qar. Her return is described as being part of "*protocol*". She's a senior officer in the First Order and would be likely to know the location of various of their assets in case of being separated from the fleet.

[image]